# Iteration over python dictionary sorted by an element

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary such as

```
 {
  'FOUR': 
     [['emit', 'build', 'simulate'], 'TestFour', 2], 
  'HELLO': 
     [['emit', 'build', 'simulate'], 'TestThree', 1]
 }
```

How can I iterate the elements based on the number 1,2? I mean, how can I get 'HELLO'(1), and then 'FOUR'(2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for x in sorted(d, key=lambda x:d[x][2]):
    print x
```

This will print

```
HELLO
FOUR
```

Comment: Do you need the `.keys()` in there?

Comment: @Gabe, indeed I do not. But it does make things more explicit, which I like.

Comment: @Gabe I have just realized that it does slow things down, so I'll heed your advice.

Comment: If you change it to `.iterkeys()` it would probably not have the same slowdown effect.

Comment: Yeah, but `iterkeys()` isn't nearly as self-explanatory as `keys()` -- might as well just leave it off entirely.

Answer (score 2):

If `d` is your dictionary:

```
for k in sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k, d=d: d[k][2]):
    ...
```

How does this work?  Firstly, we want the keys in a particular order so we use the [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in function.  `sorted` takes a `key` argument that "specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list."  The lambda provided here uses the key to retrieve the third item from the corresponding value, which is then used to sort the keys.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance: why pass `d` as a default arg in the `lambda` statement?

Comment: @senderle:  It's not needed.  It's a holdover from writing lots of lambdas for Tkinter callbacks where they're called from a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = (t[1] for t in sorted([(v[2],k) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()]))
list(my_list) == ['HELLO', 'FOUR']
```